# HTTP Basic Auth .htaccess protection works not correctly with Vue.js/Nuxt.js framework

Tags: .htaccess, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, basic-authentication, manifest.json

I have a deployed application in the staging environment (Apache server) and for protecting it I am using HTTP Basic Auth. My .htaccess config file which placed in the application folder looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /somewhere.../.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
 
Satisfy Any
RewriteEngine On
# require SSL 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I have multiple issues:

- When randomly navigating through the pages I am getting a lot of error pages without the login prompt but with the text "Unauthorized This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required";
- I am using @nuxtjs/pwa module and got a console error with text "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error." when the application tries to get the manifest.json file. After I checked the manifest.json file content from the developer's tools console I saw that it also has "Unauthorized This server could not verify..." error text and the request was with status 401Unauthorized. I don't get this error when Basic Auth is disabled;

I am using Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web browsers for testing and problem occurs in all of them.

How it can be fixed? Thanks for the help

Comment: It would seem your JavaScript(AJAX) requests are not sending an `Authorization` HTTP request header (or it's incorrect).